# COLUMN IN SQL ORDER BY CLAUSE NOT PRESENT IN SELECT STATEMENT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

As per the SQL order of execution, ORDER BY gets executed at the end, after the select statement. However, we are able to order by the result using a column that is not present in the SELECT statement. Isn't that contradictory to the order of execution? A column that doesn't exist after the SELECT Statement is being used to order by?

Looking to get an explanation

Comment: You can also order by any evaluated expression, or subquery, or constant, or function, or any combination of.

Answer (score 2):

If you ORDER BY something that isn't mentioned in SELECT, the query planner basically puts it into the SELECT as a phantom column. That's why ordering by a non-SELECTed expression (column or formula) works.

Remember, SQL is a *declarative* language, probably the only declarative language most of we programmers use. We tell SQL what we want, not how to get it. It's up to the query planner to figure out

a) whether what we asked for is well-formed and possible.

b) how to get it.

We programmers are trained, by other languages, to think procedurally. We don't tell the machine what we want, we tell it how to get it.
But that training isn't really useful for SQL. (It is useful for optimizing queries, but optimization starts with looking at the query plan revealed by EXPLAIN.)